# Javascript SVG Third-Party

Tags: library, javascript, svg

In the project that I am working, I need a third-party library that can make the followings with SVG polygons:

- I can view the origin point
- Accept a background image
- Can draw polygons that can be moved by mouse, grouped, overlayed, zoomed
- I want also to add custom properties
- I must draw them programmatically, giving coordinates serialized into the database and deserialized in a JSON format.

I looked at D3, Snap, Raphael, Draw2D, Sketch.js, svg-edit src google, but I need to find a library as simple as possible, something like a "framework" that will generate all those requirements faster.

Answer (score 1):

[Essential Diagram for JavaScript](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/diagram/defaultfunctionalities) allows you to create dynamic diagrams and serialize them to a JSON format. Simple sample application:[link](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/143239/ze/polygonsample-759937602). Note: We have used ASP.NET MVC for the serverside database integration, but you can switch that out as needed.

The whole suite of controls is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) program if you qualify. Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: I've made already a part of the application with method-draw (svgedit but much nicer interface) because it permits to draw very complex paths without problems and also exports them with json. 
Altought I looked at your alternative and it's pretty good.